# Programmatically check if pdf is a Form with iTextSharp

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to collect some metadata about pdf files on our server.  I'd like to know whether or not they are a form, and if so, if they can be saved or must be printed.  Does something like iTextSharp expose that kind of information?

Here's a code sample where I can

```vb
Private Sub GetPDFInfo(ByVal path As String)
    If File.Exists(path) Then
        Dim reader As New PdfReader(path)
        'sample metadata exposed
        Dim numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages

        'what to call to get form info?

    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Here's what I mean by being able to save or not:
[image: demo1]
[image: demo2]
I'm not sure where this information lives, but each form has some kind of indication of whether or not the form data can be saved locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to check for a form would be to see if the `PdfReader`'s `AcroForm` field is null:

```
Dim HasForm = reader.AcroForm IsNot Nothing
```

**EDIT**

I don't have Adobe Reader laying around but I think that message is generated when usage rights aren't enabled on a form. You should be able to use:

```
Dim CanUserSave = reader.HasUsageRights()
```

Comment: Awesome!  I updated my question a little to help indicate what I mean by a savable form.